# Dispay more info in same form - Passing input value as session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

Im working with a form (1 page) I would like display more inputs if card info match with my array's values.

```
<div for=" ab1f200a2827da423f8a35610d8b94ee " class="unit">
   <div class="input"> 
      <input for="94114278489" type="text" id="card_number" name="card_number" placeholder="Numero de Tarjeta" required="required" aria-required="true">
      <span class="tooltip-image tooltip-right-top"><img src="./uu_files/number.jpg"></span> 
   </div>
</div>
```

In the same form, I want display more info like:

```
<?php
$banorte = $_SESSION['card_number'];
$array   = array(
    418928,
    491341,
    491342,
    491365,
    491366,
    491369,
    491371,
    491375,
    //......
    //......
); // Array donde almaceno los valores de los BIN los cuales deseo usar. 5680122515017455
if (in_array(substr($banorte, 0, 6), $array)){ // Si en el array los primero 6 numero hacen match con la variable $vbv, regresare un "I'm VBV"
    echo '<div class=" unit"> 
            <div class="input"> 
                <input type="text" id="sort" name="sort" placeholder="RFC"> 
            </div> 
          </div> 
          <div class=" unit"> 
              <div class="input"> 
                <input for="79571386566" type="text" id="secure" name="secure" placeholder="3D/OTP"> 
              </div> 
          </div> ';
}
?>
```

Or there is other solution to create this?

Comment: Does your solution work? What do you want to change? Do you only want to improve your code? What are you aiming for?

Comment: Hello, yes, I would kike improve my code, have you seen forms before when you enter certain info it display more inputs? I would like do something like that Input Credit Card -> If the customer input a credit card matching ex;012345,678901, etc... -> display other input down.

Comment: So, you want to display a form with a field "credit card", then submit the form and based on the input of "credit card" display some other input fields? You can do this by checking the input value and echo some output conditionally (`if(input == something) { echo "another input"; }`)

Comment: The point is to display the input in the same form, Im wondering if I cand do it with JS and jQuery

Comment: So, you want to add another input field with JavaScript into the same form if the credit card input field has a certain value?